# HTML Table Query on thead and tfoot

Tags: html

What happens when we have more than one thead and tfoot tag inside a table?How does the browser respond to it?

Comment: Why would you ask this question? Try [Browser Shots](http://browsershots.org/) if you really need to test this.

Comment: Why not test it, and see for your self sir?

Answer (score 1):

It simply add another header and footer to your existing table.

You check here https://jsfiddle.net/no220phd/3/

```
<table style="width:100%">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>head1 col1</th>
<th>head1 col2</th>
<th>head1 col3</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>head2 col1</th>
<th>head2 col2</th>
<th>head2 col3</th>
</tr>
</thead>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>      
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>        
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>        
    <td>80</td>
  </tr>
    <tfoot>
    <th>foot1 col1</th>
<th>foot1 col2</th>
<th>foot1 col3</th>
    </tfoot>
    <tfoot>
    <th>foot2 col1</th>
<th>foot2 col2</th>
<th>foot2 col3</th>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: but if you put tfoot before tbody,check what happens? I need a definition for that occasion?

Comment: If you put 2 tfoot before tbody then it will display only 1st tfoot and not the 2nd one.

Comment: so the other foot tags are normally added as a row in the place it is placed